# How can I compare PostgreSQL timestamp with moment.js and specify on the date basis only?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, vue.js, momentjs

I have a small problem, where I want to know which the best solution is.
So basically I have a table with the attributes "Start" and "End".

I want to put every row in my array, where the "Start"-Date is on the current day.
So my plan, by using Axios, Sequelize and PostgreSQL, was to do it like that:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3030/worktimes/', {
  /*
  params: {
    Start: moment(new Date()) //here I just want to compare the actual date and not Date + Time
  }
  */
})
.then(response => {
  this.worktimes = response.data.data;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.worktimes));
})
.catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.data);
});
```

I am using moment.js but until now I did not had the right idea how I can use that intelligent for my case. If you also don't have a better idea I would just get everything in my array and try to trim out the time part of the "datetime" but that seems too elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

With `moment.format()` applied to both dates you can compare them by string and not by date time:

```
moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD') === moment(postgreDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: But therefor I could not use the axios-Syntax, right? So you mean its better if I just get every row and after that I should filter them by your idea?

Comment: you can uses axios-syntax too, you want to send a filter in which format, exactly ?

Comment: The format of "Start" in the database is timestamp and looks like "2019-08-12 09:37:45.977544" I guess, that called unix style? How would you express that in the Axios query?

Comment: I think its a DATETIME, you should format as `myTime.format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: getDailyProcesses(arr) {
      var dailyP = [];
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
        if(moment(arr[i].Start).format('YYYY-MM-DD') === moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {
          dailyP.push(arr[i]);
        }
      }
      return dailyP;
    }

Comment: gives me everything back

Comment: you have to push dailyP.push(moment(arr[i]).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'))